# iPhone Testing on older SDK's

Tags: iphone, version-control, sdk

I wish to test that my iPhone app works on versions older than 3.2/4.0 and currently xcode only allows those two options, making it difficult to do so.

Can someone pelase quickly link me to any tutorials, downloads, information I need to simply test the application in simulator on versions 3.1.3 and below.

Also while you're here, do i need to do anything special to test for iPod touch and the old 2g phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Xcode 3.1.3 final version in another folder other than Developer and can test for older version.